# Texas hold 'em poker game Probability task

Tags: probability-or-statistics

[image]

I wrote this code below

```
 deck = Flatten[Table[100*i + j, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 13}]];
         subsetsOf52Cards = Subsets[deck , {5}];
        holeCards = RandomSample[deck, 2]
        deck50Cards = Cases[deck, Except[Alternatives @@ holeCards]];
        hands = Flatten[Append[#, holeCards]] & /@ subsetsOf50Cards;

        pair1[{___, x_, x_, y_, y_, ___} /; x != y] := False;
        pair1[{ ___, x_, x_, ___, y_, y_, ___} /; x != y] := False;
        pair1[{___, x_, x_, x_, x_, ___}] := False;
        pair1[{___, x_, x_, x_, ___}] := False;
        pair1[{___, x_, x_, ___}] := True;  (* a pair *)
        pair1[{___}] := False;
        pairQ[hand_] := pair1[Sort[Mod[hand, 100]]];
        numberPair = Count[hands, _?(pairQ)];
        numberPair/Length[  subsetsOf52Cards];
        N[numberPair/Length[ subsetsOf52Cards]]
        0.390064
```

[image]

When I want calculate the probability of one pair I am getting 0.390064 but the correct answer  should be around 43 % I mean 0.43

Any suggestions would kind!

Comment: Please correct the title and *type* your question.

Comment: You are choosing a specific set of two hole cards initially. Most likely they are different values. But sometimes they will bee the same value, and in those cases the odds presumably rise. So you would need to average this over all possible hole cards choices.

Answer (score 2):

You need to improve your patterns:

```
pair1[{___, x_, ___, x_, ___, y_, ___, y_, ___} /; x != y] := False;
pair1[{___, x_, ___, x_, ___, y_, ___, y_, ___} /; x != y] := False;
pair1[{___, x_, ___, x_, ___, x_, ___, x_, ___}] := False;
pair1[{___, x_, ___, x_, ___, x_, ___}] := False;
pair1[{___, x_, ___, x_, ___}] := True;(*a pair*)
pair1[{___}] := False;
pairQ[hand_] := pair1[Sort[Mod[hand, 100]]];
```

This yields

```
numberPair = Count[subsetsOf52Cards, _?(pairQ)]
N[numberPair/Length[subsetsOf52Cards]]
(*1098240*)
(*0.422569*)
```

Comment: I am getting numberPair = 1013760  and NOT (*1098240*)

Comment: @poker `hands` was not defined in your post. I had to come up with something. I used `deck50Cards` for that matter. Now you still have `subsetsOf50Cards` undefined.